# Wordpress - rearrange post title, date, featured image and author

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm editing single post (single.php) in Wordpress in order to rearrange where I want to show blog **title**, **author**, **date** and **featured image**.

So far I've managed to pull **date** and **title** and **featured image**, but not **author**.

Can somebody help me out, what is the correct function to call **author**? I was also wondering if it's possible to put **featured image** as background image on the **.blog-info** element, I don't know if I can pull just the source image?

This is where I'm at so far:

```
<div class="blog-info">
  <div class="blog-date"><?php echo get_the_date() ?></div>
  <div class="blog-title"><?php echo get_the_title() ?></div>
  <div class="blog-author">written by <span class="blog-author-name"><?php echo get_the_author() ?></span></div>
  <div class="blog-image">
    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve it by adding:

```
<?php $post = get_post(); ?>
<?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
<?php echo get_the_author(); ?
```

Thanks to **Brad Holmes** for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

i will answer your image question as you say you can just pull the image into the div like so

```
<div class="blog-info" style="background-image: url('<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>')"></div>
```

as we have already fixed your author question in chat but please try not to ask two questions at a time as per rules of StackOverflow

Comment: That didn't work either. I've tried putting <?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' ) ?>

Comment: Wrapped like this? <?php $author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ); ?>

Comment: Nothing shows. Just to sum up, i've placed these two lines 
<?php $author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ); ?> 
and <?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'nicename', $author_id ); ?>

Comment: Not sure I follow. I should also mention I'm trying to pull this info outside of the loop.